# NPM command not found after installing Node via PKG (no brew)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

I tried to remove NPM and Node and reinstall them both. I'm a complete noob in the process as you'll notice.

I sadly can't remember the commands I used.

After I removed them, I ran `node -v` and it returned `command not found` and I ran `npm -v` and it returned `command not found`, so I thought the process was successful.

I then went to Nodejs website and downloaded the latest package for MacOS (v12.11.1) and ran the install. It said it was successful. I check `node -v` and it returned `12.11.1`, as expected, but then I checked `npm -v` and it sadly returned `npm not a command`!!

[image]

If I run `which node` I get `/usr/local/bin/node`. If I run `which npm` I get nothing returned.

I've since tried lots of ways of removing them both again just in case something was missed but I get the same thing every time - no NPM!

Most of the answers on StackOverflow talk about Brew but I have not used Brew and I have tried so many of the other answers but just can't get NPM back.

The PKG installer mentions this: 'Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.' but not entirely sure what that means and if that's my problem or not.

Does anybody know a surefire way to remove all traces of both, so when I reinstall the PKG from Node, I get both Node and NPM installed and working correctly?

**UPDATE:**

I seem to have had some success since posting this question. I followed instructions at https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm.html to manually remove 'everything NPM-rleated' and ran the installer again. Now when I check `npm -v` it returns to the latest version number `6.11.3`.

I will test things a bit more before deleting/answering my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem I ran the following command as suggested by [NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm.html):

> To remove everything npm-related manually:

`rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*`

All was OK after I reinstalled Node and checked NPM's version using `npm -v`.

Answer (score 0):

Googling 'Adding to $PATH mac' returns this as the top result:

https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

> Open up Terminal and run the following command:
>
> sudo nano /etc/paths
>
> Enter your password, when prompted.
>
> Go to the bottom of the file, and enter the path you wish to add.
>
> Hit control-x to quit.
>
> Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.
>
> That’s it!  To test it, in new terminal window, type:
>
> echo $PATH

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did on mac

```
rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*
brew uninstall node
brew install node
```